# Communication error code=104: Connection reset by peer [system:104] in Sabre Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am encountering an issue while interacting with the Sabre Web Service. When making a request, I receive the following response in the "groupedItineraryResponse" object:

```
"groupedItineraryResponse":{
  "version":"6.8.4",
  "messages":[
    {"severity":"Info","type":"SERVER","code":"GCA14-ISELL-TN-00-2024-03-01-L4KV","text":"27131"},
    {"severity":"Info","type":"WORKERTHREAD","code":"TRANSACTIONID","text":"7324406153805399667"},
    {"severity":"Info","type":"DRE","code":"RULEID","text":"21728"},
    {"severity":"Info","type":"DEFAULT","code":"RULEID","text":"25238"},
    {"severity":"Error","type":"AVAILABILITY","code":"PROCESS","text":"Communication error code=104: Connection reset by peer [system:104]"},
    {"severity":"Error","type":"ERR","code":"ERR","text":"Error during Processing"}
  ],
  "statistics":{"itineraryCount":0}

}
```

The error message "Communication error code=104: Connection reset by peer [system:104]" occurs under the "AVAILABILITY" type. This issue is preventing successful communication with the Sabre Web Service.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this error? Additionally, any insights into the possible causes of this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error means Sabre server sent the TCP Reset packet, and it could be network issue or action taken by server. Then we can take targeted measures. Ping to check the connection between system and server. Check Firewall or Settings blocking. Check logs both for more information. Check if your request is too large to cause a timeout. Check the rate limits of Sabre form Api document.